# Why is showonlyrefs in mathtools not working this way?

Tags: mathtools

I want to only show equations that I label/ref later in text. However I am doing something wrong, as there is not equation number shown, although I referenced it:

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\mathtoolsset{showonlyrefs}

\begin{document}
Here have an equation:
\begin{align}
A=B\label{eq:AB}\\
C=D
\end{align}
Only number equation \ref{eq:AB}.
\end{document}
```

which results in

[image: showonlyrefs fails to display equation]

Without `\mathtoolsset{showonlyrefs}` it looks fine but also equation C=D is displayed as (2):

[image: how it looks without showonlyrefs]

What should I do to solve this issue? I want that it looks exactly like in the second picture but without the (2).

Comment: `\eqref` not `\refeq` but as @campa said.

Comment: I've added an issue to myself to explain more obvious in the manual that `\ref` is not considered for `showonlyrefs` only `\eqref` (and `\refeq`)

Comment: This solved my problem. Thank you. If you make it an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `\eqref` not `\ref` to trigger the `showonlyrefs` processing.